# The best way to hash password with Django & custom user in all the possible create/save cases?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a custom user which is inherited from Django's `AbstractBaseUser` and `PermissionsMixin`. From that custom user I'm going to inherit two other user types. I'm also using Django Rest Framework.

For the custom user I've made a custom user manager which hashes the password. I already overrode the create method for serializer linked to that custom user model and models inherited from it.

I need to hash the password no matter through which functionality/method the user is created (also in the cases when a object of model inherited from the custom user is created). I also need to hash the password in case the user wants to reset his/her password (this goes for those inherited models too).

How do I ensure that? In other words, how many and what create/save methods I have to override?

---

To the architecture itself, could it be possible to use Django's default user model so that the email is a username and that username and email fields are always synced together?

Comment: wait for @alasdair he will answer your question